# Is that possible to add memory to the / partition?

Tags: 14.04, gparted, partitioning, lts

I think I made a mistake while installing my Ubuntu operation system because now there's no free space on the / partition. I already have unallocated memory though. Can that help?

Gparted Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to create a new partition in the unallocated space? If yes, that will make it easier.

Comment: no i can't because i have already  4 principal partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to boot from a USB and then resize with Gparted. The only issue is that you risk losing the partition all together. GRUB may point to an area of space for starting Ubuntu that has been moved, it doesn't seem to be as black and white as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to shift your partitions in order to make room for the root partition. I think you should be able to do it in the method:

1. Move `/dev/sda3` the left. (How much depends on how much space you want to add to your root partition).
2. expand `/dev/sda4`
3. Move Partitions if you have to, I think you might have to move partition `/dev/sda7` to the right.
4. Expand `/dev/sda6` to fill up the space you just freed up.

In order to make these changes you would have to boot from an Ubuntu Live USB. The Ubuntu Live USB comes with `GParted` So you can easily make these changes.

Comment: can't expand /dev/sda4 i think because it's busy.

Comment: You need to boot into a live USB so you can unmount the partitions to be moved.

Comment: yes as @OrganicMarble have stated you need to boot into a live usb in order to make the above changes